# mongodb: Reference previous pipeline result's array into next pipeline

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using the aggregate pipeline.

```
 const pipeline = [
                    { $match: query } // first pipeline stage
 ]
```

this would give following result:

> { "_id" : ObjectId("512bc95fe835e68f199c8686"), "author" : "dave",
>   "score" : 80, "views" : 100 }
>
> { "_id" :
>   ObjectId("512bc962e835e68f199c8687"), "author" : "dave", "score" : 85,
>   "views" : 521 }

I want to reduce this pipeline result(which is an array in this case) into an object. I know, we can reduce with project

*Second pipeline stage:*

```
{
  $project: {
   results: {
    $reduce: {
        input: <array>, // We have $$ROOT, but I need previous pipeline result
        initialValue: <expression>,
        in: <expression>
    }
   }
}
```

**How could we reference previous pipeline result as an array into this pipeline stage?**

Comment: Normally you just need to put `$name_of_your_array` in the input field of reduce. It will take the result of the last pipeline stage

Comment: Show what you are actually doing. You are almost certainly not clearly expressing what you need to do here. Easier to 1. Show some source data 2. Show desired result from that data 3. Aggregation pipeline used in your attempts so far. That's answerable.

Comment: let me know if the question is not clear.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use CURRENT

```
{
  $project: {
   results: {
    $reduce: {
        input: $$CURRENT, 
        initialValue: <expression>,
        in: <expression>
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/

Answer (score 0):

You mean [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$match": { ... } },  // your query conditions
  { "$group": { 
    "_id": "$author",
    "score": { "$sum": "$score" },
    "views": { "$sum": "$views" }
  }}
])
```

This would "group by" the `"author"` field which is placed in the `_id`and return  the other properties using an "accumulator" such as [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/)

```
{ "_id" : "dave", "score" : 165, "views" : 621 }
```

For more information I suggest looking at the [Aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) section of the official documentation which shows many samples, as well as the [SQL to Aggregation Mapping Chart](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/sql-aggregation-comparison/) if you have some familiarity with SQL Databases.